# Understanding the shell's "read" command

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I am trying to understand the UNIX shell and the "read" command is puzzling me. As the following snippet (or the "while-read" idiom) shows, this command "eats" a line of standard input.

```
(read -r foo ; echo '*** Before cat ***' ; cat) << 'END'
hello
world
END
```

Outputs:

`*** Before cat ***
world`

My questions are the following:

1. Does anyone knows of other commands having the same behavior, that is, consuming only one line of standard input and not the whole input?
2. Is it possible to write a command, without the shell's read, with a similar behavior?

Comment: `read` does exactly what you are observing: it reads exactly one line from standard input. Because both `read` and `cat` are in the same sub shell, they are sharing the file (the here document) for standard input; `read` gets the first line, then `cat` gets what is left.

Comment: You aren't seeing it in the output because you don't do anything with the variable `foo` (whose value is the string `hello`).

Comment: @chepner I believe that the OP is asking first for what other commands behave like `read` and consume _only_ one line of stdin.  A person might naively expect, for example, that `head -1` would consume only one line but it doesn't: For efficiency reasons, it reads in a buffer-full.

Comment: Thank you for these comments. @John1024 is right about my motivation, I should have been clearer that I am mostly interested in the (somewhat disturbing ?) fact that read only reads one line of input, in contrast with every other commands that I know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Default behavior

While `read` reliably reads only one line at a time, let's look at how much three other common commands consume.  `head -1` prints just the first line.  To do that, though, it consumes 8192 bytes from stdin:

```
$ seq 5000 | tee >(wc >/dev/tty) | ( head -1 >/dev/null; cat) | wc
   5000    5000   23893
   3141    3140   15701
$ echo $((23893 - 15701))
8192
```

The command `awk '{exit}'` should read the first line and exit.  To do this, though, it consumes 4096 bytes of stdin:

```
$ seq 5000 | tee >(wc >/dev/tty) | ( awk '{exit}' >/dev/null; cat) | wc
   5000    5000   23893
   3960    3960   19797
$ echo $((23893 - 19797))
4096
```

`sed 1q` should quit on the first first line read but it also consumes 4096 bytes of stdin:

```
$ seq 5000 | tee >(wc >/dev/tty) | ( sed 1q >/dev/null; cat) | wc
   5000    5000   23893
   3960    3960   19797
$ echo $((23893 - 19797))
4096
```

The quantities 8192 and 4096 appear to be buffer sizes in the current code.  One may expect that these sizes could change from one version to next version.

#### Using stdbuf

`stdbuf` is utility that attempts to control the buffer sizes that a command uses.  `stdbuf -i1` tries to set the buffer size in input to 1 byte.  With stdbuf applied, `sed 1q` consumes only one line:

```
$ (echo First; echo Second) | ( stdbuf -i1 sed 1q>/dev/null; cat)
Second
```

With `seq` as input, it still consumes only one line:

```
$ seq 5000 | tee >(wc >/dev/tty) | ( stdbuf -i1 sed 1q >/dev/null; cat) | wc
   5000    5000   23893
   4999    4999   23891
```

This same trick does not work for `head` or `awk`.  Both of these will consume several kB despite `stdbuf`:

```
$ seq 5000 | tee >(wc >/dev/tty) | ( stdbuf -i1 head -1 >/dev/null; cat) | wc
   5000    5000   23893
   3141    3140   15701
$ echo $((23893 - 15701))
8192
$ seq 5000 | tee >(wc >/dev/tty) | ( stdbuf -i1 awk '{exit}' >/dev/null; cat) | wc
   5000    5000   23893
   3960    3960   19797
$ echo $((23893 - 19797))
4096
```

#### Summary

While the shell builtin `read` reliably consumes only one line at a time, external commands, like `sed`, `awk`, and `head`, consume an implementation-dependent amount of stdin even when processing a single line.

To answer your two questions:

1. In the current implementation, it is possible to consume just one line of stdbuf using `stdbuf -i1 sed 1q` but there appears to be no guaranty that this would continue to work in any future version.
2. The example of `stdbuf -i1 sed 1q` indicates that one could write a utility that turned off input buffering and therefore consumed only as much stdin as it needed.